# The direct way to prove the convergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

For the integral $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}$$

It is possible to prove the convergence by the integration by parts but I am looking for another direct way which could be simple and more clever.

For example, to benefit from the fact $|\cos x| \leq 1$ then  to do something like $$ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{2x} = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(y)}{y} \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} $$ but I can't conclude something from this!

Comment: hint: integration by part !

Answer (score 1):

Direct application of [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals) works: antiderivative of $\cos 2x$ is bounded and $\frac{1}{2x}$ monotonically tends to zero. That's why
$$
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}
$$
converges.

Comment: so you defined $f = \cos 2x$ and g= $1/2x$ but I didn't understand this sentence "If the integral of a function f is uniformly bounded over all intervals"

Comment: @user0007 this actually means that for any $a$ and $b$ following holds: $\left| \int_a^b f(x) dx \right| < C$ for some constant $C$. "Uniformly" here means that one constant $C$ fits for all possible $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the contributions of successive half periods,

$$\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi/2}\frac{\cos 2x}{2x}dx$$ and

$$\int_{k\pi+\pi/2}^{k\pi+\pi}\frac{\cos 2x}{2x}dx.$$

As the signs alternate, the sum equals

$$\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi/2}\cos 2x\left(\frac1{2x}-\frac1{2x+\pi}\right)dx=\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi/2}\frac{\pi\cos 2x}{2x(2x+\pi)}dx.$$

Now you easily see that these terms are bounded by $\dfrac1{4\pi k^2}$ and the global sum converges.